# What's the best way to arrange subwords navigation?

Tags: cursor-motions

I want Vim to treat the following as separate words:

```
FirstSecondThird
firstSecondThird
first_second_third
first.second.third
first-second-third
first#second#third
```

What is the best solution for this? As I understand

```
set iskeyword=@,48-57,_,192-255,-,#,.,?
```

Coupled with `camelcasemotion` should do the trick.

Comment: `iskeyword=@,48-57,_,192-255,-,#,.
        Last set from ~/dotfiles/vim/plugged/vim-coloresque/after/syntax/css/vim-coloresque.vim`

Comment: You know what, it is working in a new text file. Just not in the `.html.slim` template

Comment: Yep, that was right from `.html.slim`. Here is the output from a new file: `iskeyword=@,48-57,_,192-255
        Last set from ~/.vimrc`

Comment: Here it is in `vim-coloresque`: https://github.com/gorodinskiy/vim-coloresque/blob/master/after/syntax/css/vim-coloresque.vim#125-127

Answer (score 1):

Right now I am using [camelcasemotion](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1905) plugin with the following mappings:

```
Plugin 'vim-scripts/camelcasemotion'
map w <Plug>CamelCaseMotion_w
map b <Plug>CamelCaseMotion_b
map e <Plug>CamelCaseMotion_e
sunmap w
sunmap b
sunmap e
nmap cw ce
omap iw ie
xmap iw ie
omap iw <Plug>CamelCaseMotion_iw
xmap iw <Plug>CamelCaseMotion_iw
omap ib <Plug>CamelCaseMotion_ib
xmap ib <Plug>CamelCaseMotion_ib
omap ie <Plug>CamelCaseMotion_ie
xmap ie <Plug>CamelCaseMotion_ie
```